# Why can I not make String an instance of a typeclass?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, type-systems

**Given**:

```
data Foo =
  FooString String
  …

class Fooable a where --(is this a good way to name this?)
  toFoo :: a -> Foo
```

I want to make `String` an instance of `Fooable`:

```
instance Fooable String where
  toFoo = FooString
```

GHC then complains:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Fooable String'
    (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
     where T is not a synonym.
     Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Fooable String'
```

If instead I use `[Char]`:

```
instance Fooable [Char] where
  toFoo = FooString
```

GHC complains:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Fooable [Char]'
   (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
    where a1 ... an are type *variables*,
    and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
    Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Fooable [Char]'
```

**Question**:

- Why can I not make String and instance of a typeclass?
- GHC seems willing to let me get away with this if I add an extra flag. Is this a good idea?

Comment: This is the kind of questions I upvote and mark as favorite because otherwise I know in a near future I would be asking it ;)

Comment: Regarding the extra flag: it's probably a good idea, as long as you trust GHC and understand what the flag does. [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) comes to mind: it encourages you to always use the OverloadedStrings pragma when writing Yesod apps, and QuasiQuotes are a necessity for Yesod routing rules. Note that instead of a flag at compile time, you can also put `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` (or any other pragma) at the top of your .hs file.

Comment: Take a look at [The constraint trick for instances](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/). If you want a `String` instance and not an instance for lists you would actually write `instance Char ~ char => Fooable [char] where ..` but usually you will want to follow Lemming's advice. Another approach is to enable `OverloadedStrings` and define: [`instance IsString Foo where fromString :: String -> Foo; isString = FooString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-String.html)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is because `String` is just a type alias for `[Char]`, which is just the application of the type constructor `[]` on the type `Char`, so this would be of the form `([] Char)`. which is not of the form `(T a1 .. an)` because `Char` is not a type variable.

The reason for this restriction is to prevent overlapping instances. For example, let's say you had an `instance Fooable [Char]`, and then someone later came along and defined an `instance Fooable [a]`. Now the compiler won't be able to figure out which one you wanted to use, and will give you an error.

By using `-XFlexibleInstances`, you're basically promising to the compiler that you won't define any such instances.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it might be better to define a wrapper:

```
newtype Wrapper = Wrapper String
instance Fooable Wrapper where
    ...
```

Comment: Lets say for sake of argument that I did indeed want `instance Fooable [a]` as well.  Is there a way to make the `toFoo` function behave differently if `a` is a Char?

Comment: @John: There is an extension `-XOverlappingInstances` which will allow this, and pick the most specific instance. [See the GHC user's guide for details](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap).

Answer (score 19):

You're running into two limitations of classic Haskell98 typeclasses:

- they disallow type synonyms in instances
- they disallow nested types that don't in turn contain type variables.

These onerous restrictions are lifted by two language extensions:

- `-XTypeSynonymInstances`

which allows you to use type synoyms (like `String` for `[Char]`), and:

- `-XFlexibleInstances`

which lift the restrictions on instance types being of the form `T a b ..` where the parameters are type variables. The `-XFlexibleInstances` flag allows the head of the instance declaration to mention arbitrary nested types.

Note that lifting these restrictions can sometimes lead to [overlapping instances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap), at which point, an additional language extension might be needed to resolve the ambiguity, allowing GHC to pick an instance for you.

---

*References:*:

- [Relaxed rules for the instance head](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#flexible-instance-head), in the GHC User's Guide.

Answer (score 5):

FlexibleInstances are not a good answer in most cases.
Better alternatives are wrapping the String in a newtype or introduce a helper class like so:

```
class Element a where
   listToFoo :: [a] -> Foo

instance Element Char where
   listToFoo = FooString

instance Element a => Fooable [a] where
   toFoo = listToFoo
```

See also: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_instance

Answer (score 2):

Adding to these answers, if you are not comfortable with lifting the restrictions, there may be cases where it could make sense to wrap your String in a newtype, which can be an instance of a class. The tradeoff would be potential ugliness, having to wrap and unwrap in your code.